# Creating a survival data for simulation

Tags: r, parameters, simulation, survival-analysis

I'm currently working on creating a survival model using the 'survsim' package. I would like to create a model of the **log-logistic** distribution with two parameters, **scale and shape**. However, it seems that the `simple.surv.sim` function in the 'survsim' package **does not have a place to input the parameters** of the log-logistic distribution.
My expected formula for log-logistic is `X ~ LogLogistic(theta:2, k:4)`.

The function format is as follows:

```r
library(survsim)

simple.surv.sim(
  n, foltime, 
  dist.ev, anc.ev, beta0.ev, 
  dist.cens = "llogistic", anc.cens, beta0.cens, 
  z = NA, beta = NA, x = NA
)
```

Comment: See the `rlogis()` function or maybe the "flexsurv" package and the rllogis() function.

Comment: I'm not sure what `LogLogistic(theta:2, k:4)` is supposed to represent or indicate as far as a goal. It doesn't look "mathematical" and it doesn't look like valid R code.